# jQuery attribute being added on Internet Explorer 8 when Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have found that when I view my page on Internet Explorer 8, it's adding some jQuery attribute to my element. For example:

```
<LI val="Something" jQuery15101713569792817028="118">Something</LI>
```

You can see that there is a `jQuery[SOME ID]` being added into my control, which is causing that when opening dialogs and loading its content dynamically (and don't appear to have that "JQuery attribute") it is throwing an error like the following:

> Unable to get value of the property 'jQuery15101713569792817028': object is `null` or `undefined`

This is happening when selecting an item in the list, and the problem doesn't occur in IE9. Why is this?

UPDATE:
this only happends when i use Ajax.BeginForm

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this behavior when adding events to my objects. My only guess has been it is how jQuery knows which function to fire off based on the event type and the event target.

Comment: it apears that this behavior is to prevent circular reference with lower versions of IE, but i'm still researching on that, did you had the same issue as me?

Comment: No, the behavior I've observed was the adding of attributes to the DOM objects. I've never had an issue that related to one of those attributes being present.